# Kotlin Inline function in SceneRenderer

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es

If an inline function is used in a render loop, will there be any performance benefit?

```
class SceneRenderer(val f: () -> Unit): GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
  override fun onSurfaceCreated(glUnused: GL10, config: EGLConfig) { ... }

  override fun onSurfaceChanged(glUnused: GL10, width: Int, height: Int) { ... }

  override fun onDrawFrame(glUnused: GL10) {
    ...
    inlineFun(f)
    ...
  }

  private inline fun inlineFun(f: () -> Unit) {
    f.invoke()
  }
}
```

Or is it enough to use a direct function call?

```
override fun onDrawFrame(glUnused: GL10) {
  ...
  f.invoke()
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

> Or is it enough to use a direct function call?

Yes, it is.

### Inline

[Kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions):

> Using higher-order functions imposes certain runtime penalties: each
>   function is an object, and it captures a closure, i.e. those variables
>   that are accessed in the body of the function. Memory allocations
>   (both for function objects and classes) and virtual calls introduce
>   runtime overhead.

Your function is not high-order, since it is inside the class `SceneRenderer` and there will be no reasonable impact making it `inline`.

> Inlining may cause the generated code to grow; however, if we do it in
>   a reasonable way (i.e. avoiding inlining large functions), it will pay
>   off in performance, especially at "megamorphic" call-sites inside
>   loops.

Comment: Many thanks! Clarifying question, if possible. If the function inlineFun contains more lines, as for example: 
private inline fun inlineFun(f: () -> Unit) {
  ...
  f.invoke()
  ...
}
Then the inline operator is still needed here?

Comment: Consider making something inline, only if it is higher-order (not inside declared class). If it is inside a class, don't make it inline. Lines of code don't really matter. `avoiding inlining large functions` doesn't speak amount number of lines but an amount of resources and calculations.

Comment: Now I understand). Thanks you!